# 섭리 pronounced as 섬니? Is this another sound assimilation to make it easier to pronounce?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm not used to two consonants changing sounds. It's usually just one of them that changes, so just to verify, is what I heard correct?

Comment: This happens _a lot_ with ㄹ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is nasalization applied twice.

First, 섭리 > 섭니. [Korean Standard Pronunciation](http://korean.go.kr/front/page/pageView.do?page_id=P000101&mn_id=95), Chapter 5 Assimilation of Sounds, Clause 19, Attachment reads (English translation by myself):

```
받침 ‘ㄱ, ㅂ’ 뒤에 연결되는 ‘ㄹ’도 [ㄴ]으로 발음한다.
'ㄹ' connected after syllable-final 'ㄱ,ㅂ' is pronounced [ㄴ].
```

Then, 섭니 > 섬니. Same resource, Clause 18 reads:

```
받침 ‘ㄱ(ㄲ, ㅋ, ㄳ, ㄺ), ㄷ(ㅅ, ㅆ, ㅈ, ㅊ, ㅌ, ㅎ), ㅂ(ㅍ, ㄼ, ㄿ, ㅄ)’은 ‘ㄴ, ㅁ’ 앞에서 [ㅇ, ㄴ, ㅁ]으로 발음한다.
Syllable-final 'ㄱ(ㄲ, ㅋ, ㄳ, ㄺ), ㄷ(ㅅ, ㅆ, ㅈ, ㅊ, ㅌ, ㅎ), ㅂ(ㅍ, ㄼ, ㄿ, ㅄ)' are pronounced [ㅇ, ㄴ, ㅁ] each, in front of 'ㄴ, ㅁ'.
```

So there is nothing irregular about this, and you heard it very correctly. Indeed, it is the [standard pronunciation](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/f6cba036d94846de8027c84327758697) according to the Standard Korean Language Dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there are two typical ways in pronunciation of
words : Tensification - it need a strong muscle and 비음화 - sound
from nose.

First, for 걱정, 걱쩡 (tensification). We speak strongly.

And 섭리 -> 섭니 ->
 섬니 : First change is (the initial sound of a syllable)-law.

( not 비음 ) + 비음 -> 비음 + 비음 so that ㅂ+ㄴ -> ㅁ+ㄴ